# How to I limit the number of tagged blog posts listed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, hexo

I have a hexo blog with tags in the sidebar.

The code below lists all the tags for each of the blog posts.

What do I do to limit the tags listed, to only display the tags with 2 or more posts?

```
<% if (site.tags.length){ %>
<div class="widget-wrap">
  <h3 class="widget-title"><%= __('tags') %></h3>
<div class="widget">
  <%- list_tags({show_count: theme.show_count}) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tagcloud`](https://hexo.io/ru/docs/helpers.html#tagcloud) helper, instead of [`list_tags`](https://hexo.io/ru/docs/helpers.html#list-tags).

Here is [example](https://github.com/theme-next/hexo-theme-next/blob/3db4fc2e1f51dd9b0eae8d159e3638f4d5f3fbc5/layout/page.swig#L45). Maximum tags there – 300.